# In ESRI Arcade, is there a wildcard or a NOT LIKE function?

Tags: attributes, esri, arcmap

I am trying to find a wildcard function and not like in Arcade.

I have tried to find a wildcard function. I tried *, $, %.
I tried the 'NOT LIKE' AND <>. Maybe I am writing this all wrong?

This script here says if the entry is not AY, return false.

```
if ($feature.Parcel_No  != 'AY') return false
return true
```

However, I want for it be like anything not starting with AY, return false.
This is how it would look if it's written as a SQL Clause

```
if ($feature.Parcel_No  OT LIKE 'AY%') return false
return true
```

This is written for Attribute Rule Constraint.

[image: Expression Builder]

Comment: Doesn't look like [tag:vbscript] so why is that tagged in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Left function in arcade to achieve this:

https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/text_functions/#left

```
return Left($feature.Parcel_No, 2) == 'AY'
```